# Im receiving a String index out of range question for a java program i wrote for my assignment

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I would like to apologise in advance if im doing something wrong with the code formatting because this is my second time posting here
I have a java assignment due in a couple of days in which the user enters a string and only the integers are collected from it and placed in the array intArray
Now i think i got the logic right in the code below but when i run it in the main, it asks for the string and the boolean, when i enter both it gives me the error
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 115"

This is what i entered for example
"Enter a string and true if you want to skip errors or false if you want to skip errors
sdak23
false"

this is my main:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class MainStringToIntArray {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner intut = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    StringToIntArray s1 = new StringToIntArray();
    System.out.println("Enter a string and true if you want to skip errors or false if you want to skip errors");
    s1.scanStringToIntArray(intut.next(), input.nextBoolean());
}
```

}

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringToIntArray {

```
private int[] intArray = new int[10];

public StringToIntArray() {
    Arrays.fill(intArray, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
}

public int indexOf(int intToFind) {
    int b = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < intArray.length; a++) {
        if (intArray[a] == intToFind) {
            b = intArray[a];
        }
        else {
            b = -1;
        }
    }
    return b;
}
public int indexOf(String intToFind) {
    int b = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < intArray.length; a++) {
        if (intArray[a] == Integer.parseInt(intToFind)) {
            b = intArray[a];
        }
        else {
            b = -1;
        }
    }
    return b;
}
public boolean contains(int intToFind) {
    int a = indexOf(intToFind);
    if (a > 0) {
        return true; 
    }
    else { 
        return false;
    }
}
public boolean contains(String intToFind) {
    int a = indexOf(intToFind);
    if (a > 0) {
        return true; 
    }
    else { 
        return false;
    }
}
public int get(int index) {
    if(index < 0 && index > 10) {
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }
    else {
        return intArray[index];
    }
}
public boolean scanStringToIntArray(String s, Boolean skipErrors) {
    
    Boolean result = null;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(s);
    
    int l = s.length();
    
    if ((skipErrors)) { 
        String discard = null;
        for (int a = 0; a < l; a++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < l; z++) {
                if (input.hasNextInt(s.charAt(z))) {
                    intArray[a] = s.charAt(z);
                    System.out.println(a);
                    result = true;
                }
                else {
                    discard = discard + s.charAt(z);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int v = 0; v < l; v++) {
            for (int p = 0; p < l; p++) {
                if ((input.hasNextInt(s.charAt(p)))) {
                    intArray[v] = s.charAt(p);
                    System.out.println(v);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println(v);
                    result = false;
                }
                
                
            }
        
        }
        
    }
    return result;
            
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to use StringToIntArray?

Comment: It was in the instructions to have a no args constructor that sets the value of all the elements of the array to integer.min value

Comment: Are you all set?

Comment: Unfortunately no, i still have this problem

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the `get` method. It is logically impossible for the index to be both less than 0 and greater than 10; you probably want to use the logical or operator (`||`). Also, the maximum index of the array is actually 9, as arrays are zero indexed.

```
public int get(int index) {
    if(index < 0 || index > 9) {
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }
    else {
        return intArray[index];
    }
}
```

There are other logical errors in your code as well. All your indexOf methods should be returning the index where the element was first found instead of the element itself and your else branch is always resetting it to -1 each time it is not found.

Comment: Hello
thanks a lot for your help
I actually fixed the get method but im still receiving the same erro

Comment: As for the indexOf methods, if the intToFind is not found, it is supposed to return -1 indicating that the number was not found
I will make it return the index number of the place where it was found instead of the element itself,
But the rest of the program is still giving the same error